# When using `ContractFunction.build_transaction` from a contract factory you must provide a to address with the transaction

Tags: solidity, web3.py, contract-debugging

I am getting the error in the title when trying to update the contract with a function I wrote. Any help with this? If I change 'from' to 'to' and use my address it also doesn't work properly. I am using w3.py

```
store_transaction = Voting_Contract.functions.addPoll("First Test.").buildTransaction(
{
    "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
    "chainId": chain_id,
    "from": my_address,
    "nonce": nonce + 1,
}  # this is creating a transaction

signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
store_transaction, private_key=private_key
)
# we send the transaction
send_store_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)
print("Contract Updated.")
# we wait for the transaction to finish
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_store_tx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first call the contract constructor and then the function you want to call. In your case it will be:

```
store_transaction = Voting_Contract.constructor().buildTransaction(
{
    "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
    "chainId": chain_id,
    "from": my_address,
    "nonce": nonce,
} 

signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
   store_transaction, private_key=private_key )

send_store_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)`
```

(your function call)